# Speeding up multiple seeks by prefilling ifstream buffers

Tags: c++, filestream, seek

I want to speed up thousands of seeks and reads increasingly forward in a 1G contiguous section of a huge file(~10G) at a known offset(say 8G). i.e. the pattern looks like: `seek(8.00G), read(128 bytes), seek(8.01G), read(56 bytes)`, and onward.

**Basic Pseudocode** - Approach 1

```
int known_offset = 8*1024*1024;
std::ifstream fs("fname", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary)
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    fs->seekg(known_offset, std::ios::beg);
    fs->read(buf, 128);
    known_offset += calculate_fwd_offset_based_on_buf(buf)
}
```

**Possible Improvement** - Approach 2
I thought about increasing the ifstream read buffer size so that it prefetches and fills the buffer, so that the following seeks use the buffer to avoid/reduce disk seeks. Something along the lines of:

```
char buf[8*1024*1024];
std::ifstream fs("fname", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary)
fs.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 8*1024*1024);
// Remaining code remains same
```

Now I ran `strace/time` commands on the approaches from method (1) and (2). The time taken is longer for approach (2) and exactly the same number of LSEEK/read calls happen  in both with larger reads happening in case (2) which is my guess as to why its taking longer. Is there any way to have `seekg/read` work as expected?

**Inconvenient Solution**
I can get the above approach to work by removing `seekg(next_offset)` and doing a `fs.read(buf, num_chars_to_next_offset)` instead. This reduces the number of reads from 9000 to ~40. I would really prefer that it work for seeks though as I am unnecessarily copying characters into a noop buffer this way.

Comment: Did you look into [file mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/file-mapping)?

Comment: I cant use mmap for this specific use case - Have to use iostreams due to some later processing being done with `boost::iostreams` filters and other reasons.